# MySQL: percentage of filled field

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following MySQL table `user`.

```
Name | Phone | City
---------------------
Mike | 154   | London
NULL | 659   | Paris
Matt | NULL  | NULL
NULL | NULL  | NULL
Marc | 514   | NULL
```

Expected Result:

```
COUNT of 3/3 not NULL | COUNT of 2/3 not NULL | COUNT of 1/3 not NULL
---------------------------------------------------------------------
1                     | 2                     | 1
```

I would like to know the number of users who completed his profile 100%, 66%, 33%, 0%.

What query can give me this result?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation for this:

```
Select  Sum(Case When TotalNotNull = 3 Then 1 Else 0 End) As `Count of 3/3 not NULL`,
        Sum(Case When TotalNotNull = 2 Then 1 Else 0 End) As `Count of 2/3 not NULL`,
        Sum(Case When TotalNotNull = 1 Then 1 Else 0 End) As `Count of 1/3 not NULL`,
        Sum(Case When TotalNotNull = 0 Then 1 Else 0 End) As `Count of 0/3 not NULL`
From
(
    Select  Case When Name  Is Not Null Then 1 Else 0 End 
        +   Case When Phone Is Not Null Then 1 Else 0 End
        +   Case When City  Is Not Null Then 1 Else 0 End
            As TotalNotNull
    From    `User`
) As A
```

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm...

```
select ((Name is not null) + (Phone is not null) + (City is not null)) as numNotNull
from user
group by numNotNull;
```

This puts on the information on separate rows rather than in a single row, but that seems useful.

If you want it in columns:

```
select sum(3 = (Name is not null) + (Phone is not null) + (City is not null)) as 'COUNT of 3/3 not NULL',
       sum(2 = (Name is not null) + (Phone is not null) + (City is not null)) as 'COUNT of 2/3 not NULL',
       sum(1 = (Name is not null) + (Phone is not null) + (City is not null)) as 'COUNT of 1/3 not NULL'
from user;
```